# MEF and Prism integration

Tags: prism, mef

I need your advice deciding on a new project architecture I'm going to implement.

Can I use MEF and Prism side by side?

Is it too complex to accomplish this?

Can make the same stuff Prism does with MEF?

Right now, two features Prism gives, but are not in MEF are Regions and the Event Aggregator. Can I do everything else with MEF, rather than Prism?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a MEF extensions project called [MEFContrib](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/), which provides integration of MEF and Unity, Prisms default IoC container: [Unity Integration](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation%20%26%20Features)

Answer (score 2):

A very quick Google search reveals you are not the only person thinking about this.  I will provide you a few good results (this time ;-) ):

Here is Glenn Block (one of the developers of MEF) talking about it an linking to some pretty well implemented articles on the subject:
http://blogs.msdn.com/gblock/archive/2010/01/03/mef-and-prism-exploration-mef-module-loading.aspx

Information about the use of MEF in the next version (4.0) of Prism:
http://blogs.msdn.com/dphill/archive/2009/12/09/prism-and-mef.aspx

There's a lot more information out there.  I searched for "MEF Prism" to find this info.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

MEF is a dependency injection manager .Prism is a framework which helps to build modular and composable application.With Prism you can totally seperate UI from business logic.You can use Prism and MEF together to create Hiighly  modualr application.